# understanding javascript return statement why it is returned undefined

Tags: javascript

I was working on the below javascript code, could someone explain why below code output is `undefined`?

Given a year, find the date of the  `256th` day of that year according to the official Russian calendar during that year.

Then print it in the format `dd.mm.yyyy`.

```js
function solve(year) {
  if (year < 1700 || year > 2700) {
    return false;
  } else if (year >= 1700 && year <= 1917) {
    if (year % 4 === 0) {
      var days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
      calculate(days)
      `enter code here`
    }
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
    calculate(days)
  } else if (year > 1918 && year <= 2700) {
    if (year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0)) {
      var days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
      calculate(days)
    }
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
    calculate(days)
  } else if (year === 1918) {
    var days = [31, 15, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
    calculate(days)
  }

  function calculate(days) {
    var daysOfSep = 256 - days.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator + currentValue
    }, 0)

    return `${daysOfSep}.09.${year}`
  }
}

console.log(solve(1918))
```

Comment: Mmm, i wonder if this can be golfed

Comment: Yes it can be. [Here is in only 180 characters](https://tio.run/##TY3LCoMwEEX3/kVBJYEok1jrA8d8SClRo5YW0aJtQdRvt3HXzczhcGfus/yWkx4fr7fXD3Wz7y0qzFXGI4B1VbkwW0KqyTXgjKgMecIjqZyzFHEqklThYWLJw9RIAERzRgwacF3lcIATApUmKmLKzJMA/ia/MUUtjaRmM8W8sJfaH5v6oxtCSlYZVXoVE@GFbj4kvr3MW2FZeuinoWv8briTlhz9lO77Dw)

Answer (score 2):

Because you are not returning within your main function, by default a function expression returns undefined:

```
function solve(year){
        if(year < 1700 || year > 2700) {
          return false;
        }else if(year >= 1700 && year <= 1917) {
          if(year%4 === 0) {
            var days = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31];
            calculate(days)`enter code here`
      }
          var days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31];
          calculate(days)
       }else if(year > 1918 && year <= 2700) {
         if(year % 400 === 0 || (year%4 === 0 && year%100 !== 0)) {
         var days = [31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31];
         calculate(days)
       }
      var days = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31];
      return calculate(days) //calculate inner function returns the result, but you do not return this.
    }else if(year === 1918) {
      var days = [31,15,31,30,31,30,31,31];
      return calculate(days) //calculate inner function returns the result, but you do not return this.
    }

        function calculate (days) {
          var daysOfSep = 256 - days.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
           return accumulator + currentValue
          },0)

          return `${daysOfSep}.09.${year}`
        }
    }

    console.log(solve(1918))
 26.09.1918
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are calling `solve()` function first and inside of `solve()` function again you are calling `calculate()` function. You have return value only inside of `calculate()` function not in `solve()` function that's reason you are getting `undefined`

Your code should be like this.

**DEMO**

```js
function solve(year) {
  if (year < 1700 || year > 2700) {
    return false;
  } else if (year >= 1700 && year <= 1917) {
    if (year % 4 === 0) {
      var days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
      calculate(days)
      `enter code here`
    }
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
    return calculate(days)
  } else if (year > 1918 && year <= 2700) {
    if (year % 400 === 0 || (year % 4 === 0 && year % 100 !== 0)) {
      var days = [31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
     return  calculate(days)
    }
    var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
    calculate(days)
  } else if (year === 1918) {
    var days = [31, 15, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31];
   return  calculate(days)
  }

  function calculate(days) {
    var daysOfSep = 256 - days.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue) {
      return accumulator + currentValue
    }, 0)

    return `${daysOfSep}.09.${year}`
  }
}

console.log(solve(1918))
```